# Fazer busca de palavra dentro de uma lista e retornar tuplas ordenadas em PYTHON

Tags: python, python-3.x, tupla

O algoritmo deve receber uma string, contar quantas palavras iguais e retornar uma lista de tuples com as palavras que mais aparecem na string e quantas vezes ela aparece.
O problema é que nas buscas é palavras que começam iguais ele conta mais vezes. Tipo: "but" e "butter", ele conta but 3X e butter 2X.
"betty bought a bit of butter but the butter was bitter"

Ainda desejo ordenar primeiro pelas palavras que aparecem mais e caso apareçam um numero de vezes igual, pela ordem alfabética das palavras.
Tipo: "falling" e "down", ambas aparecem 4X, por isso na saida ordenar primeiro "down" e depois "falling".
"london bridge is falling down falling down falling down london bridge is falling down my fair lady"

```
def count_words(s, n):   
top_n = []
itens = n
words = s.split()
pref = words
for p in pref:
    cont = 0
    for w in words:
        if w.startswith(p):
            cont+=1
    if (p, cont) not in top_n:
        top_n.append((p, cont))
top_n.sort(key = lambda t:t[1], reverse = True)
#from operator import itemgetter
#sorted(top_n, key = itemgetter(1), reverse = True)
while len(top_n) > itens:
    del top_n[len(top_n)-1]    
return top_n

def test_run():
    print count_words("cat bat mat cat bat cat", 3)
    print count_words("betty bought a bit of butter but the butter was bitter", 3)
    print(count_words("london bridge is falling down falling down falling down london bridge is falling down my fair lady", 5))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_run()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def count_words(s, n):   
    top_n = []
    itens = n
    words = s.split()
    top_n = dict([])
    for w in words:
        if w not in top_n.keys(): top_n[w] = 0
        top_n[w] +=1
    top_n = list(top_n.items())
    #print(top_n)
    top_n.sort(key = lambda t:(-t[1],t[0]), reverse = False)
    return top_n[:n]

def test_run():
    print(count_words("cat bat mat cat bat cat", 3))
    print(count_words("betty bought a bit of butter but the butter was bitter", 3))
    print(count_words("london bridge is falling down falling down falling down london bridge is falling down my fair lady", 5))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_run()
```

Creio que assim fica mais claro, a idéia aqui é usar as palavras como chaves de um dicionário, fazendo assim a contagem. O problema da ordenação é que você deseja que seja ordenado decrescente pela contagem e de forma crescente pela palavra, o que fiz ali foi transformar o número em negativo `-t[1]`, ordenando primeiramente pela versão negativa do número e depois pela palavra, agora de forma decrescente.

Comment: De uma olhada no `collections.Counter` também -

Answer (score 2):

```
from operator import itemgetter
import re

sentence = 'london bridge is falling down falling down falling down london bridge is falling down my fair lady'

def count_words(text):
    words = re.findall(r'\w+', text)    
    wordsCount = [(words.count(word), word) for word in set(words)]        
    wordsCount.sort(key=itemgetter(1)) #order by word
    wordsCount.sort(key=itemgetter(0), reverse=True) #order by wordcount   
    return wordsCount

print(count_words(sentence))
```

Resultado: [[4, 'down'], [4, 'falling'], [2, 'bridge'], [2, 'is'], [2, 'london'], [1, 'fair'], [1, 'lady'], [1, 'my']]

A função acima utiliza re.findall para localizar as palavras e em seguida realiza a contagem das palavras, retornado na lista wordsCount, uma sequência de listas com cada uma das palavras do texto e o respectivo número de ocorrências. Em sequência utilizamos a função sort para ordenar a lista, primeiro alfabeticamente e em seguida de acordo com o número de ocorrências, destacando-se que a função sort persiste a ordenação alfabética realizada no primeiro passo.

Uma solução bastante legível e em poucas linhas.